# Secure cookies and Path Length Constraint

Tags: certificates, cookies

Using apache 2.2.3 on oracle enterprise linux.

When setting following setting in httpd.conf:
**Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure** , 
cookie generation (which happens on our registration page) stops.

In certificate we have "Path Length Constraint=None" set. Its a L1C entrust cert. Can it be cause of it ?

Comment: i would set the secure flag using a different method...  Perhaps this is a better question for StackOverflow.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the certificate. Try using a literal/static value in the cookie name, and check the headers coming out of the server.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: Is that cookie actually served via HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between cookie processing, and certificate extensions. The path length constraint (in the `Basic Constraint Extension` of a CA certificate) enforces a limit on the length of the certificate path beyond that CA; with a path length constraint equal to 1, that CA certificate is good for issuing non-CA certificates (e.g. a certificate for a SSL server), but not for issuing other CA certificates.

Cookies occur at the HTTP level, when the SSL tunnel has been successfully established. There is no HTTP, hence no cookie at all, if something goes wrong with the SSL tunnel; conversely, when cookies come into action, everything already went fine with the SSL handshake, in particular the validation of the server certificate and the processing of certificate extensions that this entails.

Answer (score 0):

It in the end turned out the issue with specific builds of Apache Installed on our webserver. 
Surprising all were 2.2.3 version, but some of the affected were having the release date previous than others.

Upgrading apache to same version resolved the issue.